# How do I clear a screen efficiently

Tags: c++11

Whenever I try to make a game or something that requires the rapid clearing of a screen, I've used system("CLS"). I now know that that is not good to use so I tried using a for loop to print new lines rapidly. While this works it looks really weird and less clear. I've seen people try to use STRING to clear a screen but whenever I try it it never works. How can I clear my screen efficiently and cleanly.

Comment: I've heard its supposed to be bad when using on non-windows platforms or something so I'm just trying to shake the habit.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to clear the screen. But in any case, actually clearing the terminal and redrawing will be far too slow and glitchy for many games.

You should use either your OS's native terminal handling functions, or a cross-platform library that abstracts them.
I'd recommend [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/), which is the latter. It basically provides an interface akin to a double-buffered graphics API, and handles all of the actual terminal twiddling so the frame swap is as fast as possible.

Comment: I'm only new to C++ so I'm just doing basic ASCII games and whatnot right now but I've seen people using something like cout << string("\n", 100); Is that something you can't do any more because I can never get it to work

Comment: @EthanJones that prints one hundred newlines, scrolling the previous frame out of view (pretty much like `cls`, actually). It works as a technique, but as I said it is really slow. Native terminal handling enables operations such as "just add a capital `O` at (8, 15)", and that makes the update that much faster.

Comment: Right thanks. I guess I'll probably find ways to do it when I properly start doing graphics but until then, thanks I'll look into ncurses.